# App shows blank Activity

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am fetching data with an API, Storing & then display as a list view. But My app shows blank Activity. I am using ContentProvider. Here are my codes. Kindly help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.so;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        Adapter adapter;
        Model[] model;
        DataDbHelperr dbHandler;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            dbHandler = new DataDbHelper(this);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Databse initialized");

            FetchDataTask dataTask = new FetchDataTask();
            dataTask.execute();

            adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Model[]> {

            private final String LOG_TAG = FetchDataTask.class.getSimpleName();

            private Model[] getDataFromJson(String dataJsonStr)throws JSONException {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(dataJsonStr);
                JSONObject json_data = object.getJSONObject("data");

                JSONArray json_feed = json_data.getJSONArray("feed");

                Model[] model = new Model[json_feed.length()];
                //final String POSTER_URL = "http://so-images/:";

                for (int i = 0 ; i < json_feed.length(); i++){
                    model[i] = new Model(
                            json_feed.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"),
                            json_feed.getJSONObject(i).getString("imageUrl")
                    );
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG," title of data "+json_feed.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"image url "+json_feed.getJSONObject(i).getString("imageUrl"));

                    String title = model[i].getTitle();
                    String imageURL = model[i].getImageUrl();//

                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(com.example.so.data.DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_TITLE, title);
                    contentValues.put(com.example.so.data.DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_URL, imageURL);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Content Value contains data");
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"content uri checking "+ com.example.so.data.DataContract.DataEntry.CONTENT_URI);
                    getContentResolver().insert(com.example.so.data.DataContract.DataEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Data is inserted successfully");
                }
                return model;
            }

            @Override

            protected Model[] doInBackground(String... params) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"in the do in  background task");

                // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
                // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
                String dataJsonStr = null;

                try {
                    // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                    // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                    // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                    URL url = new URL("http://s-o.co.in:1302/api/v2/delhi/feed/5");
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "URL " + url.toString());

                    // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    // Read the input stream into a String
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        // Nothing to do.
                        return null;
                    }
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                        // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                        // buffer for debugging.
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                        // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                        return null;
                    }
                    dataJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"JSON Data"+dataJsonStr);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);                
                    return null;
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (final IOException e) {
                            Log.e("Fetch data task", "Error closing stream", e);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Parsing the JSON string
                try {
                    return getDataFromJson(dataJsonStr);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Model[] strings) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"ON POST EXECUTE METHOD IS CALLED");
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        com.example.so.data.DataContract.DataEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
                Model models = new Model();

                while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    models.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                    models.setImageUrl(cursor.getString(2));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Title here " + models.getTitle());
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Image url here "+models.getImageUrl());
                }
                adapter.add(models);//
            }
        }
    }
```

**Adapter.java**

```
package com.example.so;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;    
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
        //Model[] models = new Model[];
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public Adapter(Context context) {
            this.context=context;
        }

        public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> models) {
            this.context = context;
            this.models = models;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return models.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return models.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            View rootView = convertView;
            if (rootView == null){
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageUrl);
                holder.title = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                rootView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)rootView.getTag();
            }
            Model model = (Model) getItem(position);
            holder.image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(model.getImageUrl()));
            return rootView;
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            ImageView image;
            TextView title;
        }

        public void add(Model model){
            models.add(model);
        }
    }
```

**Model.java**

```
package com.example.so;

    public class Model {

        private String title;
        private String imageUrl;

        public Model() {
        }

        public Model(String title, String imageUrl) {
            this.title = title;
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getImageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }

        public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
    }
```

**DataContract.java**

```
package com.example.so.data;

    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.provider.BaseColumns;

    public class DataContract {

        public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.so";

        public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

        public static final class DataEntry implements BaseColumns {

            // table name
            public static final String TABLE_DATA = "data";

            public static final String _ID = "_id";
            public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
            public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_URL = "imageUrl";

            // create content uri
            public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                    .appendPath(TABLE_DATA).build();
            // create cursor of base type directory for multiple entries
            public static final String CONTENT_DIR_TYPE =
                    ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_DATA;

            // for building URIs on insertion
            public static Uri buildDetailsUri(long id){
                return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
            }
        }
    }
```

**DataDbHelper.java**

```
package com.example.so.data;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;


    public class DataDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public static final String LOG_TAG = com.example.so.data.DataDbHelper.class.getSimpleName();

        //name & version
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "delhiData.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        public DataDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            final String SQL_CREATE_DELHI_DATA_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+
                        DataContract.DataEntry.TABLE_DATA + "(" +
                        DataContract.DataEntry._ID+
                        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_TITLE+
                        " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_URL+
                        " TEXT NOT NULL" +
                    ");";

            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_DELHI_DATA_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " +
                    newVersion + ". OLD DATA WILL BE DESTROYED");
            // Drop the table
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DataContract.DataEntry.TABLE_DATA);
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" +
                    DataContract.DataEntry.TABLE_DATA + "'");

            // re-create database
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }
```

**DataProvider.java**

```
 package com.example.so.data;

    import android.content.ContentProvider;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.UriMatcher;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.util.Log;


    public class DataProvider extends ContentProvider {

        private static final String LOG_TAG = com.example.so.data.DataProvider.class.getSimpleName();
        private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
        private DataDbHelper dataDbHelper;

        // Codes for the UriMatcher //////
        private static final int DELHI = 100;

        private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
            // Build a UriMatcher by adding a specific code to return based on a match
            // It's common to use NO_MATCH as the code for this case.
            final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
            final String authority = DataContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreate() {
            dataDbHelper = new DataDbHelper(getContext());
            return true;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

            Cursor cursor = dataDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                    DataContract.DataEntry.TABLE_DATA,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            return cursor;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String getType(Uri uri) {
            final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

            switch (match){
                case DELHI:
                    return DataContract.DataEntry.CONTENT_DIR_TYPE;
                default:{
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
                }
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

            final SQLiteDatabase database = dataDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Uri returnUri;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"in the insert method");
            long _id = database.insert(DataContract.DataEntry.TABLE_DATA, null,values);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"after inserting ");
            // insert unless it is already contained in the databaseWeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI
            if (_id > 0) {
                returnUri = DataContract.DataEntry.buildDetailsUri(_id);
            } else {
                throw new android.database.SQLException("Failed to insert row into: " + uri);
            }
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            return returnUri;
        }

        @Override
        public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have lots of log methods in your code. What is in log after you launch your app?

Comment: try to move Model models = new Model(); to inside while.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated MainActivity.java -

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                Model models = new Model();
                models.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                models.setImageUrl(cursor.getString(2));
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Title here " + models.getTitle());
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Image url here "+models.getImageUrl());
                adapter.add(models);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Adapter.java**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        View rootView = convertView;
        if (rootView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageUrl);
            holder.title = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            rootView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)rootView.getTag();
        }
        Model model = (Model) getItem(position);
        try {
            holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
            //holder.image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(model.getImageUrl()));
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(models.get(position).getImageUrl())
                    .into(holder.image);
            holder.image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG," Error here "+e);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

**Now I am able to fetch title but still not able to fetch images. Kindly suggest.**